# Ubuntu Server static Route through ubuntu PC

Tags: networking, ubuntu-10.04, tcp, static-routes

Working my way through understanding Linux.

I still consider myself a newbie. I recently installed a 10.04 server with LAMP and others on it. I wish to get it surfing the net: apt-get update and install webmin.

**My setup:**
Ubuntu 10.04 PC
Ubuntu 10.04 SERVER

**PC connects to www through WiFi**:

**netstat -r**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Iface
10.0.0.0 * 255.255.255.0 U wlan0
192.168.122.0 * 255.255.255.0 U eth0
link-local * 255.255.0.0 U eth0
```

**ifconfig -a**

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 6c:f0:49:c1:20:48 
inet addr:192.168.122.100 Bcast:192.168.122.255 Mask:255.255.255.0

lo 
Link encap:Local Loopback 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host

wlan0 

Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:1f:1f:3c:f5:37 
inet addr:10.0.0.4 Bcast:10.0.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
```

**SERVER connects:**

```
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Iface
192.168.122.0 * 255.255.255.0 U eth0
default 192.168.122.100 0.0.0.0 UG eth0
```

**When I ping from server:**

```
ping 10.0.0.4 - GOOD
ping 192.168.122.100 - GOOD
ping -b 192.168.122.253 OR 0 - GOOD
```

in `/etc/network/interface`

I have defined Gateway as `192.168.122.100`

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have any idea how to get the server to get to the Internet through the PC? They see each other, the server sees the ip given by the WWW router to the PC but he does not exit through it.

I did some experimenting here trying to replace the gateway with all sorts but with no luck.

Tried:

```
up route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.122.253 (=router static ip)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Havee you enabled ip forwarding (routing) on your PC ? - do `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: Thanx nos,Just did but the situation is at still.
I think the problem is with my eth0 configuration.

Comment: I must admit, I am completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you have a default gateway defined, I don't have a  linux system right here but the routing table should have something like:

0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 gw gateway_ip  (and of course you should be able to reach your gateway from your computer).

Once that you have that, ping something known...www.yahoo.com for example, but not the the name URL, do it to its IP. From my home: 69.147.125.65

With that solved, you only need to set up your dns server IP, in /etc/resolv.conf, or let your dhcp

Comment: I kind of understand, so let me try please: when you say default gateway, you mean for server? and is for server, what should it be: the router's ip? the station's eth0 ip? the wifi dungle's ip? hence: 192.168.122.253 OR 192.168.122.100 OR 10.0.0.4?

Comment: Better yet, let me ask: what should /etc/network/interfaces config look like for server? static ip 192.168.122.200 netmask 255.255.255.0 **gateway ???.???.???.???...** and is there an `inet route add -net` command added? what is it suppos to look like?

Comment: Hello Jadeye:  Please execute this as root on your system: route add default gw 192.168.122.253           I don't know how to add a new line in this editor, but please realized that  you should hit enter after the gw IP (192.168.122.253)...Now, I am assuming that whatever is at 192.168.122.253 has a route to the internet. If that is the case, please ping 69.147.125.65, if successful, then ping www.yahoo.com.

Comment: My /etc/network/interfaces just show:   auto lo and iface lo inet loopback.

Comment: Hey MisterWalrus,
Ok, so for <ENTER> here you do SHIFT+ENTER in the messege box.

Q: When you say: "on your system" you mean the PC connected to the web or the server trying to get the gateway?

Just to make sure we are on the same page here:
SERVER needs web connection
PC has web connection through WiFi dungle ip 10.0.0.4
Server ip 192.168.122.200
PC ip 192.168.122.100
Router static ip 192.168.122.253

What do I need to do to get SERVER through to the internet???

And if it is as you say, where do I do "sudo route add default gw 192.168.122.253"? Server OR PC?

Thanx,

JadeYe.